Fonts got fuzzy/chunky after reconnecting monitor
System is MacMini M1 2020 running Sonoma 14.4.1, Monitor is HP 24mh - 1920x1080.
UPDATE: All the info below was true, except that what I hadn't done was disconnect the power to the monitor. I had just disconnected the monitor from the computer. After a little time away and a chance to clear my head I decided, in desperation, to unplug the monitor and plug it back in. FIXED! The old adage "try a complete reset FIRST" still applies and is highly recommended!

I recently had to disconnect the system completely, move it, and reconnect. The first thing I noticed is that (unless I'm completely crazy) the font quality worsened dramatically - not only in menus but in all apps. It used to be acceptably sharp, but now has gotten fuzzy around the edges and chunky looking (bolder). I've checked that the display resolution is set at default and have tried turning font smoothing of and on. "On" is better because at least the smaller fonts are readable. At 92ppi I don't expect perfection, but I'm sure it was better.
Is there anything in the process of reconnecting the monitor that could have caused this?
I installed BetterDisplay but don't see that anything there that makes a difference.
Thanks for any ideas or suggestions.
